# ARIMA model won't work: error in optim function

Tags: r, optimization, arima

hopefully someone can help me out.

I want to do an autoregressive regression on some monthly logreturns (60 observations). I found that only lag 1,3,11,18 are significant, so I only want to include those in the regression (see object `model`).

I keep on getting the error of `non-finite finite-difference value`, which I can't bypass. I tried two things that I found on the web:

1. I tried setting `optim.method = "Nelder-Mead"`, which gives me the output below.
2. I tried setting `optim.method = "Nelder-Mead"` and `hessian = FALSE`, but then it gives the error that `hessian` is not a valid argument.

```
> model
 [1] NA  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA NA
> arima(log_returns, order = c(18,0,0), fixed = model, include.mean = TRUE)
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [3]
In addition: Warning message:
In arima(log_returns, order = c(18, 0, 0), fixed = model, include.mean = TRUE) :
  some AR parameters were fixed: setting transform.pars = FALSE
```

```
> arima(log_returns, order = c(18,0,0), fixed = model, include.mean = TRUE, optim.method = "Nelder-Mead")
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [2]
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In arima(log_returns, order = c(18, 0, 0), fixed = model, include.mean = TRUE,  :
  some AR parameters were fixed: setting transform.pars = FALSE
2: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
3: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
4: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
5: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
6: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
7: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
8: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
9: In log(s2) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: As I read this, you want us to read your error messages without the code that produced them. Are you assuming that there is only one way to get that error message? I think a [MCVE] is needed for almost any error message. Hence my close vote.

Comment: I believe every piece of code (except for the actual log_returns, but I described that) necessary is there. What part do you believe is still insufficient?

Comment: It does not appear that you have a syntactic error.  Rather it appears the some aspect of your data is creating problems with the mathematics. That’s seems like a fairly complex model for such a small dataset. But that’s about all that can be said about such an error without a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and setting an `xreg` value of `1:length(data)` worked for me.

```r
arima(data, order=c(p, d, q), xreg=1:length(data), method="ML")
```